# How to running SWF file in a Website without their loading it complete first

Tags: javascript, html, swfobject, swfupload

This is what is happening, I make a catalogue on adobe indesign and export a `swf` file with an `html` (the software makes that for default when you want to create an animated catalogue.

I upload my catalogue (both `.html` and `.swf` files) [here](http://cosmoscreativeagency.com/CATALAGO%20ALANIC%20PARA%20WEB%20NUEVOO.html)
but, like you see spent too much time to load, think that's cause the file load complete and not with parts.

I want it to load page by page that's possible?

Maybe adding a javascript code or something?

Answer (score 1):

Using swf is cutting you off many devices. Did you give a try with HTML Export from iNDesign ? If limited, you have plugins like in5 that can output nice stuff.
Also, you can also choose epub3 format that makes your document compatible with most tablets and yet preserve the initial layout.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Post this in the comments

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it load in page by page, it's essentially one big file.

You can separate it into multiple files, then you could load it in using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys thanks for the help... the problem with it is that I need the animations as you see in the file I sent you there is a animation every time I change of page... so ..... it will be awesome to keep that